# Removing control/space characters from cache key in python

Tags: python, base64, memcached

I have to remove control/space characters from my cache key. It is giving following error:

```
MemcachedKeyCharacterError: Control/space characters not allowed (key=' :1 :ZjE3MDJiNDY4NjI3OGJlY2ZmYzg4YmFhYmU2ZjRiN2E4MzU1NTMyYw==\n')
```

The code which I am using is:

```
class CachedAPIView(APIView):
    def get_object(self,request):
        s = hashlib.sha1()
        s.update('Messages')
        returnData=cache.get(base64.encodestring(s.hexdigest()),None)
        if not returnData:
            obj=function(self,request.data)
            s = hashlib.sha1()
            s.update('Messages')
            cache.set(base64.encodestring(s.hexdigest()),returnData)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
base64.encodestring(s.hexdigest()).strip()
```

PS. You dont need to calculate `s.update('Messages')` twice. You can even cash `s.hexdigest()`.

```
cache.set(…,returnData)
```

is wrong because you don't have returnData — you checked its absense with `if not returnData`. Do you mean

```
cache.set(…,obj)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet below is offered simply as a means to correct the input string, however I'm sure there is another, more specific, solution to your problem. With this invalid string, I use str.split with a `:` delimiter to produce a list object - and I only want the portion after the last `:`, so of the returned list object, I grab the last item, specifying the last index `[-1]`, and now with the original string (excluding everything before the last `:`) I invoke the method `.strip` to remove the unwanted newline character, resulting in what I believe should be a valid string for you to use.

```
>>> temp = ' :1 :ZjE3MDJiNDY4NjI3OGJlY2ZmYzg4YmFhYmU2ZjRiN2E4MzU1NTMyYw==\n'
>>> key_string = temp.split(':')[-1].strip()
# ZjE3MDJiNDY4NjI3OGJlY2ZmYzg4YmFhYmU2ZjRiN2E4MzU1NTMyYw==
```